# VBA: Find the missing numbers in one range from the others

Tags: excel, compare, range, difference, vba

I want to compare two ranges (Range 1 and Range2) in Excel and list or publish the list of the missing numbers in either of them.

Eg.: Range 1= 1,2,3,4,5,6
     Range 2= 1,3,4,6

I want to display 2,5 as the missing numbers

Please help me in achieving them using Excel VBA

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's better method, but this will write missing numbers in Cell C1

```
Sub Missing()
    String_Array = Split(Range("A1"), ",")
    For I = 0 To UBound(String_Array)
        If InStr(1, Range("B1"), String_Array(I)) = 0 Then
            If Range("C1") <> Empty Then Range("C1") = Range("C1") & ","
            Range("C1") = Range("C1") & String_Array(I)
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutjaylee's answer doesn't work.  It only check if all Elements in Range 1 are in Range 2.  If String_Array(I) = 1 then InStr(1, Range("B1"), String_Array(I)) will return true if if Range("B1") = "2,3,10"

**Try this:**

```
Sub Missing()
    Dim resultString As String
    Dim arr1()  As String
    Dim arr2()  As String
    arr1 = Split(Range("A1"), ",")
    arr2 = Split(Range("B1"), ",")

    CompareArrays arr1, arr2, resultString
    CompareArrays arr2, arr1, resultString

    Range("C1") = resultString
End Sub


Sub CompareArrays(arr1() As String, arr2() As String, resultString As String)
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim bFlag As Boolean
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr1)
        bFlag = False
        For j = 0 To UBound(arr2)
            If arr1(i) = arr2(j) Then
                bFlag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not bFlag Then
            If (Len(resultString)) Then resultString = resultString & ","
            resultString = resultString & arr1(i)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```